# How to set/get GPS Accuracy on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, gps, emulation

is there any way to set or get GPS accuracy in Android Emulator? Via Telnet I can set longitude and latitude but no accuracy. Is there any way?

Or how Android calculates accuracy in general, is there any way to influence it?